# PHP Checkbox stay checked or unchecked on page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page that auto refreshes itself every 9 seconds.

Also have a checkbox echo like this:

```
echo "<li><b>DHCP Starved?</b> <input type ='checkbox' id ='DHCPs'> </li>";
```

There is a checkbox on the page but it will un-checks itself after page refresh.

How do i make it stay checked if it's check and unchecked if its unchecked.

PS: I also have no understanding of Jquery, am pretty new to PHP/HTML in general.

Folder Tree: [image: The line of code above is in index.php in this folder tree]

The line of code above is in index.php in this folder tree

Comment: when you refresh the page of course that check action is gone, you need some persistent way of saving that action, probably cookies or localstorage

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use jQuery to listen checked event and set value to localStorage.

```
  $(function() {
    $("#DHCPs").attr("checked", localStorage.getItem("DHCPs_checked") == "true");

    $("#DHCPs").click(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        localStorage.setItem("DHCPs_checked", "true");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("DHCPs_checked", "false");
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hello, how do i use this? Do i just add it after my line?

Comment: add it in your html file

Comment: There's a problem, my HTML and PHP are in the same "page."

Comment: you can write html code in .php file, put it before ‘<?php’ or after ‘?>’

Comment: Can you link me to an example?

Comment: @Coln sorry can't help you anymore, it would be better to ask someone near you, someone who can see your computer, I think you should learn how PHP, HTML, Javascript work, at least very basic

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
echo "<li><b>DHCP Starved?</b> <input type ='checkbox' id ='DHCPs' name='DHCPs' checked> </li>";
```

in your php code.what value you want to insert you can write here instead of 0 or 1

```
'DHCPs' => ($this->input->post('DHCPs') == "on") ? 1 : 0
```

Comment: This will always check the box, if I uncheck the box and refresh, the box will be checked again. OP asks about how to retain the state of the checkbox after refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pull the the data from the database and run a test like this

```
    echo "<li><b>DHCP Starved?</b> <input type ='checkbox' id ='DHCPs' <?php 
($data)?'checked':''; ?> > </li>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (untested):

```
$('#DHCPs').on('click', function() {
  if ($('#DHCPs').is(':checked')) {
    localStorage.setItem('dhcps', 'checked');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('dhcps', 'unchecked');
  }
}
```

Now you can use localStorage.getItem to check the checkbox state.

Comment: Hello, how do i use this? Do i just add it after my line?

Comment: @Kyaw 's answer is more complete, what might be better for you. You need to implement the jQuery inside <script type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Hi, i saw his comment but i'm not sure what to do with it? Can you link me to an example?